# req.body returns empty object on put request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Im trying to update data by using put request 
im using method-override package and multer for file upload 
im not able to figure out what is causing the problem because
my post route is working fine where objects are getting stored in database from req.body fields and file is getting uploaded

this is my route:

```
app.put("/browse/:id", function(req, res){
  console.log( req.body); // returns empty object
  console.log( req.file); //undefined
})
```

this is the form

```
<form action="/browse/<%= book._id %>?_method=PUT" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">

        <input value="<%= book.image %>" type="file" name="image" >
        <input value="<%= book.title %>" type="text" name="title" required>
        <textarea name="desc">
          <%= book.description %>
        </textarea>

        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit"> Update </button>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, i guess just forgot to put the `upload.single('image')` method in there. That solved it for me.